# ¿Como ocultar Auth en Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, autenticación

El problema es el siguiente:

Yo tengo una aplicación desarrollada en *Angular 4* y una *API* desarrollada en *nodejs*. Resulta que le mando un *header* a mi *API* con una *Api-key* determinada y esta me devuelve la información siempre y cuando la *Api-key* sea correcta.

Ahora el problema es que la *Api-key* es visible para todo el mundo. Ya que desde la DevTools(Networks) se puede ver la información mandado por el header.

[image: Consola de network]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna manera de poder ocultar la *Api-key*? o al menos ¿Existe alguna otra forma mas segura de proteger estos datos personales?

Comment: Es una API pública?

Comment: Si ya que tiene conexión con otros dominios.

Comment: Al ser la API pública cualquiera puede acceder a la apikey, aunque no sea desde tu aplicación yendo al origen de esta API así que si no quieres hacerlo no es un paso necesario

Comment: Lo que quiero es tener la mayor seguridad para mis API´s claro esta que de esta forma yo puedo exceder fácilmente. Ahora como hago para evitar esta vulnerabilidad. A lo mejor tengo que reemplantear la pregunta.

Comment: Ocultarla en el developer tools no es posible. La única protección es que no te las intercepten en transito. La autenticación se hace con cookies, headers de autorización como tu caso o una combinación de ambos. Si lo que te preocupa es que se accedan a tus apiKeys deberias usar [JWT](https://jwt.io/) y almacenar en el server sólo las cabeceras para que un ataque a la base de datos no revele dicha información.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que desde el servidor debes poner una politica del mismo origen y restringir para que otros dominios no tengan acceso a la API sino solo tu dominio.

En NodeJs seria algo como:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  //console.log('allowedOrigins origin: ',req.headers.origin);
  let allowedOrigins = ["http://misitioweb"];
  let origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Accept, x-xsrf-token, x-access-token');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Lo segundo es que cuando ya pongas el proyecto en produccion debes adquirir un certificado ssl para cifrar todos los datos y asi no habra problema si alguien intercepta los datos por que la key ira cifrada.